# Prononciation en français des mots d'origine anglaise

Tags: anglais, prononciation

Je voudrais savoir quelle est la règle qui détermine la prononciation en français d'un mot d'origine anglaise (ou bien des mots d'informatique).

Par exemple, **rugby** se prononce en français différemment qu'en anglais.
De même, le langage de programmation **Python**.
Je n'arrive pas à comprendre la logique. Comme d'autres exemples : le **week-end** et le **camping**.
Bien sûr, il existe d'autre mots mais je ne m'en souviens pas. En plus, quand un mot de telle origine garde sa prononciation originale ?

Comment: [Python](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(serpent)) n'est pas un mot anglais.

Comment: @mouviciel Certes, ce n'est pas un mot anglais. Or, Python c'est un langage de programmation dont son créateur Guido van Rossum voulait rendre hommage à son série télévisée anglaise préférée "Monty Python's Flying Circus" d'où le nom du langage. Donc, c'est entendu qu'il faut le prononcer comme en anglais (paɪˈθɒn).  Mais, cela c'est mon idée:-)!

Comment: Autre exemple: F.B.I. est prononcé avec un accent _Èf-Bi-Aïe_ mais C.I.A. est prononcé sans accent _Cé-I-A_, pourtant les 2 sont des acronymes d'entités similaires.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de règle absolue, c'est souvent l'usage qui dicte la prononciation des mots étrangers, comme celle des mots français d'ailleurs...

Les mots comme python, Apache, Oracle, Android (androïde), Ruby (rubis), interface, etc. qui existent déjà en français ou qui ont une structure familière garderont une prononciation française.

Certains mots comme budget ont été pleinement (ré)adoptés il y a longtemps et ont une prononciation régulière.

Rugby s'est peut-être prononcé un temps « reugby » /rœgbi/, mais il a perdu son caractère anglais il y a longtemps.

Dans beaucoup d'autres cas, un mot anglais aura souvent une prononciation qui se rapprochera de la prononciation anglaise, mais en gardant, en France au moins, des phonèmes compatibles avec le français. Il y aura donc la plupart du temps une perte des voyelles allongées, des diphtongues, des accents toniques non réguliers et un remplacement des consonnes inexistantes en français par les consonnes perçues comme les plus proches, en particulier th devient z, le r anglais devient un r français. Le -ey final est prononcé [e] au lieu de [ɪ] en anglais.

Les combinaisons inconnues ou rares en français comme les doubles lettres oo, ee et ea ont une prononciation établie, /u/ et /i/. Elles peuvent entraîner des prononciations mixtes, comme babyfoot où la première partie est souvent prononcée à la française et la deuxième à l'anglaise /babifut/.

Un autre exemple de prononciation mixte est cow-boy /kobɔj/

Les terminaisons des mots importés en -an, -on, -et, -ing gardent la prononciation de la consonne finale, avec absence de nasalisation là où elle aurait été présente dans un mot français.

Il existe quelques cas particuliers comme Nike qui est prononcé en français  /najk/ à l'image de Mike et donc ni comme il se doit en [anglais américain](https://youtu.be/w4TWm5Q8SuQ) « naïki » /naɪkiː/, ni, pour des raisons compréhensibles, comme le voudrait l'étymologie grecque Nikê /nike/.

Comment: Just to illustrate the variation here, i say /bebifut/ and /kɔbɔj/. In some cases, it's regional: "stand" is pronounced /stɑ̃/ in Switzerland, /stɑ̃d/ in France and /stand/ in Canada and in Belgium.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse exhaustive. Bien que je sois grec je n'avais pas réalisé l'origine du nom Nike. Merci encore ! Après avoir vu votre réponse, la situation est bien plus claire. Je voudrais seulement vous poser une autre question pourtant que cela s'éloigne de la question initiale. Cette francisation des mots d'origine anglaise (y compris l'accent tonique comme dit l'autre réponse que j'ai reçue) est reliée de quelque façon avec les problèmes que les écoliers et les étudiants de licence confrontent avec l'anglais et plus particulièrement  avec sa prononciation?

Comment: J'ai moi aussi mentionné l'accent tonique (une perte des accents toniques non réguliers). Comme la règle de position des accents toniques en français est figée et ne présente pas d'exceptions, il est difficile pour un français qui ne maîtrise pas d'autres langues de placer un accent tonique ailleurs que sur la dernière voyelle non muette. Quant aux difficultés des écoliers et étudiants, je ne pense pas qu'elles soient fondamentalement différentes de celles que rencontrent les locuteurs d'autres langues. Chaque langue induit un accent plus ou moins caractéristique causé par ses propres limites.

Comment: Bien sûr, vous avez vous aussi en parlé. Je m'excuse. En plus, je ne désirais certainement pas insulter les Français. Je travaille à une université et j'essaie d'expliquer d'où viennent les difficultés et la lathophobie que les étudiants ont avec l'anglais (d'après mon expérience au moins). En cherchant sur Internet l'on lit : loi Toubon,  doublage systématique des box office films parmi les raisons données.

Comment: Pas de problème. Il n'y avait de toute façon rien d'insultant pour les français dans le commentaire. Le doublage systématique des films, séries et plus généralement de toute intervention télévisée y est sûrement pour beaucoup, seules les chansons ne sont pas doublées, mais comme elles ne sont jamais sous-titrées, les français ne comprennent souvent pas les paroles, ou très peu. Le problème est identique pour l'Italie ou l'Espagne, ou même l'Allemagne où le niveau en grammaire et vocabulaire est meilleur, mais l'accent reste souvent très prononcé. Pour ce qui concerne la lathophobie...

Comment: ..., c'est peut-être une caractéristique française. Quelqu'un qui s'écarte de la prononciation française pour se rapprocher de la prononciation anglaise sera c'est vrai souvent l'objet de moqueries à l'école...

Comment: J'ajouterai que par rapport aux étudiants dont la langue maternelle est germanique, il y a une plus grande distance avec l'anglais (sinon pour le vocabulaire au moins pour la structure) et le fait qu'il n'y ait pas vraiment d'accent tonique en français est une difficulté supplémentaire.

Comment: Il semblerait que les britanniques prononcent "naïk" et non "naïk-i" comme les américiains. S'il fallait revenir à l'origine grecque, on aurait pu franciser en "nikè", mais quelque chose me dit que cela aurait causé quelques problèmes ;)

Comment: @XouDo Ah oui, seuls les Étatsuniens prononcent "naïk-i", mais ce sont eux qui on créé la marque. Pour ce qui est de la prononciation étymologique française, oui, ç'aurait été un choix hasardeux... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Je veux aussi ajouter que l'accent tonique (la force qu'on met sur une syllabe plus qu'une autre) pour les anglicismes est presque toujours mis sur la dernière syllabe, comme pour tous les mots en français.

Par exemple, en anglais on dirait « rugby » avec l'accent tonique sur la première syllabe («rug»). En français, on le mettrait sur la dernière syllabe («by»). Il y a plus d'information ici : https://regardsurlefrancais.com/2016/10/08/laccent-est-sur-la-derniere-syllabe-en-francais/

Comment: Par exemple, en anglais on dirait « rugby » avec l'accent tonique sur la première syllabe («rug»). En français, on le mettrait sur la dernière syllabe («by»). Il y a plus d'information ici : https://regardsurlefrancais.com/2016/10/08/laccent-est-sur-la-derniere-syllabe-en-francais/

Comment: Merci, n'hésitez pas à ajouter ça au contenu de la réponse directement lors d'une mise à jour. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Généralement, quand on prononce un mot d'une autre langue dans notre langue native, on utilise une prononciation assez proche à la phonologie de notre langue native. Utiliser une prononciation étrangère est considéré prétentieux par de nombreuses personnes, comme prononcer coyote (en anglais) comme `ko-yo-te`, la prononciation en espagnol.