# Prononciation différente des « u » de « club » et « rugby »

Tags: anglais, prononciation, voyelles, emprunts

Je me demande pourquoi le *u* de ces deux mots ne se prononce pas identiquement.
Plus précisément, pourquoi *rugby* est francisé tandis que *club* se prononce presque comme en anglais.

Comment: Hmm, tu as déjà posé à peu près la même question il y a huit mois... https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29071/1109

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prononciation en français des mots d'origine anglaise](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29071/prononciation-en-fran%c3%a7ais-des-mots-dorigine-anglaise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux mots ont en fait été emprunté initialement avec un /y/ au XIXe siècle, [le TLFi citant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/club) même une prononciation avec un /ɔ/ ouvert pour club en 1841. C'est l'époque des chelins pour les shillings et jongle pour jungle (d'ailleurs le "jungle" moderne est très adapté également).

Au fil des deux siècles suivants, avec la connaissance croissante de l'anglais, mais aussi de la diversité des langues dans le grand public, les prononciations de beaucoup de mots d'emprunt se sont rapprochées de celle de leur source.

C'est ainsi que /ʃəlɛ̃/, /klyb/ ou le belge /wekɛn/ sont devenus /ʃiliŋ/, /klœb/ et /wikɛnd/ (shilling, club et weekend, donc). D'autres termes sont cependant resté identique à leur prononciation initiale, issue de l'orthographe ou fortement francisée. En plus de rugby, on pourrait citer baffle (/bafl/ plutôt que /bafœl/ ou /bɛfœl/), jungle (/ʒœ̃gl/ plutôt que /dʒœngœl/), shampoing (/ʃɑ̃pwɛ̃/ plutôt que /ʃampuiŋ/ ou /ʃɑ̃puiŋ/) ou encore stud (/styt/ plutôt que /stœd/ - le mot belge populaire pour des crampons de foot).

Il est cependant difficile d'expliquer pourquoi certains mots restent intouchés par ce phénomène. La conscience qu'il s'agit d'un emprunt doit avoir un rôle, mais ce n'est pas la seule explication, sans quoi shampoing n'aurait pas la prononciation qu'il a.

Ce processus de défrancisation des emprunts, alimenté par le prestige qu'a actuellement le bilinguisme, se poursuit bien entendu de nos jours. "Congo", fermement /kɔ̃gɔ/ quand j'étais enfant est maintenant concurrence par la variante /kɔngɔ/. Il peut aussi différer de région en région, en témoigne un mot comme "stand", prononcé /stand/ à l'anglaise au Canada et en Belgique, /stɑ̃d/ avec une voyelle nasale en France et /stɑ̃/ en Suisse, sans consonne finale et avec voyelle nasale.

Comment: Merci pour cette contribution aussi savante qu'intéressante. Je me permettrais juste d'ajouter ma suspicion (partisane ?) relativement au *u* de *rugby* resté très "français" : En France, ce jeu à d'abord et longtemps été pratiqué dans la région du sud-ouest. Cette même région qui, depuis Aliénor, avait pris l'habitude d'adapter la prononciation des mots anglais. Ainsi *rugby* est d'abord devenu *rugueby* avec un premier u... "*bien de chez nous*"... ;-) On notera d'ailleurs d'autres mots du vocabulaire anglais de ce sport dont la prononciation est restée très *française* (*maul->mol*...)

Answer (score 0):

On doit cela en partie à l'esprit sans systématique dans lequel les emprunts de mots anglo-saxons sont faits, à l'esprit fantaisiste des uns et des autres. Pourquoi KO (kao) et OK (okay)? Parce que dans « KO » le k est en début de mot? Je ne pense pas que ce soit la raison. En allemand le mot « club » a une prononciation allemande (kloup) comme le mot « jungle ». On doit cette inconstance en bonne part à cet esprit sans motivation suffisante à préserver un système qui fait que de nos jours le mot « ko » en allemand est prononcé « ko » alors que « ok » est prononcé « okay » (bien que k soit « ka » en allemand), cet esprit qui fait que le monde soit  enclin surtout à  se laisser mener par l'instinct du « keep up with the Jone's », cet esprit relativement malléable face au pouvoir coercitif de la multitude. Pourquoi « djoni » et pourquoi « jonatan », dans chaque cas la forme citée étant la seule en odeur de sainteté?