# Prononciation du mot "challenge"

Tags: anglais, prononciation, anglicismes

[Challenge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/challenge) :

1. (Anglicisme) Défi, épreuve.

La prononciation logique, et utilisée, est \ʃa.lɑ̃ʒ\, mais, réemprunté à l’anglais, le mot est depuis le XXe siècle généralement prononcé à l’anglaise.

Quelle règle particulière dicte que ce mot se prononce à l'anglaise ?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la question. Tu demandes pourquoi il est généralement prononcé à l'anglaise ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tu as raison ! Je ne comprends pas pourquoi pour ce mot c'est la prononciation à l'anglaise qui domine.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Les étudiants prononcent Python à la française et pas à l'anglaise. Python est un langage de programmation dont son créateur Guido van Rossum voulait rendre hommage à son série télévisée anglaise préférée "Monty Python's Flying Circus" d'où le nom du langage. Donc, c'est entendu qu'il faut le prononcer comme en anglais (paɪˈθɒn). Comme l'on le fait pour challenge. Ce n'est pas logique autrement, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: *Python* est aussi un mot français depuis très longtemps, aucune raison de le prononcer à l'anglaise. *Challenge* est un réemprunt récent (milieu du 20e siècle), apparemment quelques dixaines d'années n'ont pas suffit à franciser la prononciation (je ne sais pas combien de temps il faut en général, ni si c'est systématique).

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29071/prononciation-en-fran%C3%A7ais-des-mots-dorigine-anglaise

Comment: @jlliagre C'est ma question :-)! Effectivement je me rappele ça et cette question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32057/prononciation-diff%C3%A9rente-des-u-de-club-et-rugby?noredirect=1&lq=1 Cependant, il me paraît toujours bizarre. Anyway...j'accepte qu'il n'y pas de règles systématiques.

Comment: @jlliagre De toute façon, je crois que l'usage de challenge n'est pas recommandée. On doit utiliser défi ou d'autres mots purement français. Donc la question même peut  être sans sens.

Comment: Challenge est couramment utilisé en français. Quant à la pureté, c'est une notion très relative. Le *challenge* anglais vient de l'ancien français *chalenge/calenge*, du latin vulgaire *callengia* et classique *calumnia*, lequel a aussi donné *calomnie*...

Comment: J'allais rédiger un truc mais il y a tout dans la réponse de Jlliagre de ton ancienne question... En gros, ça dépend, on prononce comme on peut avec les phonèmes du français, et il y a souvent plusieurs prononciation qui coexistent avant qu'une s'impose, en fonction de sa facilité de prononciation, de son euphonie, du niveau d'anglais moyen des gens qui l'utilisent le plus, etc.